# App disappearing after upgrading to Gradle 3

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play, android-launcher

I pushed out a new release for my android application to the play store for beta testers. The testers are able to update/install the new version, but afterwards the app is not displayed anywhere on the device. The play store also only has the option to Uninstall (whereas most applications have an "Open" option).

This push includes upgrading the app to Gradle 3 so I'm assuming the issue might pertain to that.

Sorry if this has been asked before I couldn't find any similar posts. 
Thank you for any help!

Heres some of my Gradle (*ed out private info):

```
def bbBuildNumber = "4";
if (project.hasProperty('BUDDYBUILD_BUILD_NUMBER')) {
    bbBuildNumber = project.properties['BUDDYBUILD_BUILD_NUMBER'];
}

android {
    signingConfigs {
        prodConfig {
            keyAlias '**** development'
            keyPassword '****'
            storeFile file('*******')
            storePassword '****'
        }
        devconfig {
            keyAlias 'key1'
            keyPassword '****'
            storeFile file('*******')
            storePassword '****'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId '*******'
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 341
        versionName "1.9"
        testInstrumentationRunner "*******"
        buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_NUMBER", "\"${bbBuildNumber}\""
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_NUMBER", "\"${bbBuildNumber}\""
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
        preDexLibraries = false //delete the already predexed libraries
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError true
        ignoreWarnings false
        lintConfig file('../config/lint.xml')
    }
    //flavorDimensions "dev", "prod"
    flavorDimensions "prod"
    productFlavors {
//        devConfig {
//            minSdkVersion 16
//            applicationId '*******'
//            targetSdkVersion 26
//            testInstrumentationRunner '******'
//            versionCode 341
//            versionName '1.9'
//            dimension "dev"
//            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
//            javaCompileOptions {
//                annotationProcessorOptions {
//                    includeCompileClasspath false
//                }
//            }
//        }
        prodConfig {
            minSdkVersion 16
            applicationId '*********'
            targetSdkVersion 26
            testInstrumentationRunner '******'
            versionCode 341
            versionName '1.9'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.prodConfig
            dimension "prod"
            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
            javaCompileOptions {
                annotationProcessorOptions {
                    includeCompileClasspath false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Heres the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="*******">
    <application
        android:name=".dagger.******"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/****">
        <activity
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:name="****.android.ui.splash.SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="app" android:host="****.com" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.*.android.ui.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.*.android.ui.TabbedActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.*.android.ui.forgot.ForgotPasswordActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_forgot_password"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.MainActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.*.android.ui.support.SupportActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_support"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.*.android.ui.forgot.ForgotUsernameActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_forgot_username"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.MainActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.*.android.ui.transfer.DoTransferActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/card_transfer_title"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.TabbedActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.*.android.ui.transfer.bank.BankTransferActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/bank_transfer_title"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.TabbedActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.*.android.ui.transfer.destination.DestinationPickerActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.*.android.ui.transfer.amount.AmountPickerActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.*.android.ui.transfer.confirm.ConfirmationActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.*.android.ui.transfer.result.ResultActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.*.android.ui.settings.notifications.NotificationsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.*.android.ui.settings.timestamp.TimestampPickerActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.*.android.ui.settings.document.DocumentsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.*.android.ui.settings.accounts.BankAccountsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.TabbedActivity"
            android:label="@string/bank_accounts_title">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.*.android.ui.settings.accounts.EditBankAccountActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.TabbedActivity"
            android:label="@string/edit_account_title">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.*.android.ui.profile.ProfileWebview"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.*.android.ui.settings.accounts.AddBankActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.TabbedActivity"
            android:label="@string/add_account_title">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.*.android.ui.settings.accounts.CurrencyExchangeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.TabbedActivity"
            android:label="@string/currency_exchange_title">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.*.android.ui.transfer.cashpickup.CashPickupActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.TabbedActivity"
            android:label="@string/cash_pickup_title">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.*.android.ui.history.CashPickupDetailsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.TabbedActivity"
            android:label="History"
            ></activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="********" />
    </application>

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you modified your Manifest? Note that there are applications that can't be opened, so they doesn't appear in launcher and in Play Store doesn't appears the Open button. Examples of that kind of applications are launchers (as an aplication) or license application which only are useful to buy a license key for an app or set of apps.

Comment: The only updates to the manifest were the addition of two activities. My thought is that the app is being considered one of those apps like you mentioned that don't open but I'm not sure why

Comment: Could you share your Manifest, please? I've just test that if you removes the <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/> in the intent filter for your main activity, the app is installed but doesn't appears in the launcher.

Comment: Hey I just added the manifest. I do have that LAUNCHER field though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in your Manifest whether at least one activity (usually your main activity) has the correct `intent-filter` as follows:

```
    <activity
        android:name="your.package.YourMainActivity">            
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Your main activity should declare the **action MAIN**

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
```

and the **category LAUNCHER**

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
```

If there is no activity in your Manifest with the **category LAUNCHER**, the app will not be shown in the launcher.

Comment: Hey I just added my manifest. It looks like I already have that field.

Comment: In your manifest you are setting the launcher category, but then a few lines below you are setting the category to default. Test if removing this line the app appears now. Also try to temporary delete the browser category. @DavidThurman

Comment: Youre awesome Marc! It had something to do with these 4

Comment: <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

I removed them all and that fixed the issue. Im not sure the specific cause but you pointed me in the right direction!

Comment: I'm glad that heloed you! :)